# How do I make Tkinter support PNG transparency?

Tags: python, png, transparency, tkinter

I put in a partially transparent PNG image in Tkinter and all I get is this

[image]

How do I make the dark triangle on the right clear? (like it's supposed to be)

This is python 2.6 on Windows 7, btw.

Comment: Can you confirm that the image appears with transparency in another program?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's an example (the PNG file example.png has lots of transparency in different places):

```py
from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, Canvas
import ImageTk

t = Tk()
t.title("Transparency")

frame = Frame(t)
frame.pack()

canvas = Canvas(frame, bg="black", width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

photoimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="example.png")
canvas.create_image(150, 150, image=photoimage)

t.mainloop()
```

You need to make sure the image has been stored as "RGBA" which is RGB with an alpha channel. You can check for that using a graphics program of your choice, or using PIL ([Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)):

```py
import Image
im = Image.open("button.png")
print im.mode
```

This should print "RGBA". If not, you'll have to make sure the alpha channel is saved with the image. You'll have to consult your graphics program manual for how to do that.

Comment: It might me noteworthy that `ImageTk` is not part of the Python standard library, but of the Python Imaging Library, which has to be installed seperately. Also, PIL has not yet Python 3 support, so the above code will only work on Python 2.x.

Comment: @fbmd: Good comments. Here's a related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896286/image-library-for-python-3

Comment: PIL has been forked by and more or less superseded by the pillow package, which *does* support 3.x.