# Image library for Python 3

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

What is python-3 using instead of PIL for manipulating Images?

Comment: Did you check the media module? (import media)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: media is not in the standard library of python3

Comment: I didn't think that PIL was standard either. But looks like I'm wrong

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: No, you're right, PIL is not in the standard library.

Comment: One should install `Pillow` from PyPI which should be a drop-in replacement for `PIL`; this is the preferred package on Python 2 too.

Answer (score 96):

The "friendly PIL fork" **[Pillow](http://python-pillow.github.io/) works on Python 2 and 3**. Check out the [Github project](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow) for support matrix and so on.

Comment: It is [still actively being developed](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/releases) as for Oct 2014, [has a nice doc](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/index.html), you may `pip3 install Image` (I was using pillow without knowing), and [you `from PIL import Image`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/tutorial.html). It also supports [all the major platforms](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#platform-support) now. When looking for a PIL for python3, this is definitely the choice.

Answer (score 18):

Christoph Gohlke managed to build PIL (for Windows only) for python versions up to 3.3: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

I tried his version of PIL with Python 3.2, and image open/create/pixel manipulation/save all work.

Answer (score 13):

Qt works very well with graphics. In my opinion it is more versatile than PIL.

You get all the features you want for graphics manipulation, but there's also vector graphics and even support for real printers. And all of that in one uniform API, [**`QPainter`**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html).

To use Qt you need a Python binding for it: [**PySide**](http://www.pyside.org/) or [**PyQt4**](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download).
They both support Python 3.

Here is a simple example that loads a JPG image, draws an antialiased circle of radius *10* at coordinates *(20, 20)* with the color of the pixel that was at those coordinates and saves the modified image as a PNG file:

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

app = QCoreApplication([])

img = QImage('input.jpg')

g = QPainter(img)
g.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
g.setBrush(QColor(img.pixel(20, 20)))
g.drawEllipse(QPoint(20, 20), 10, 10)
g.end()

img.save('output.png')
```

But please note that this solution is quite 'heavyweight', because Qt is a large framework for making GUI applications.

Answer (score 6):

As of March 30, 2012, I have tried and failed to get the sloonz fork on GitHub to open images.  I got it to compile ok, but it didn't actually work.  I also tried building gohlke's library, and it compiled also but failed to open any images.  Someone mentioned PythonMagick above, but it only compiles on Windows.  See [PythonMagick on the wxPython wiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/PythonMagick).

PIL was last updated in 2009, and while it's website says they are working on a Python 3 port, it's been 3 years, and the mailing list has gone cold.

To solve my Python 3 image manipulation problem, I am using `subprocess.call()` to execute ImageMagick shell commands.  This method works.

See [the subprocess module documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess).

Answer (score 5):

You can use my package [mahotas](http://luispedro.org/software/mahotas) on Python 3. It is numpy-based rather than PIL based.

Answer (score 5):

You want the **[Pillow](http://python-pillow.org/) library**, here is how to install it on Python 3:

```
pip3 install Pillow
```

If that does not work for you (it should), try normal `pip`:

```
pip install Pillow
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what is needed, [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/) may be the best choice, with manipulations going way beyond PIL and the current version of Pillow.  Very well-maintained, at least as much as Pillow.  Also, the underlying data structures are from Numpy and Scipy, which makes its code incredibly interoperable. Examples that pillow can't handle:

[image: Region Adjacency Graph Merging]

[image: Radon Transform]

[image: Histogram of oriented gradients]

[image: Approximate and subdivide polygons]

You can see its power in the [gallery](http://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/).   [This paper](https://peerj.com/articles/453.pdf) provides a great intro to it.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Python3 you can also use the library PILasOPENCV which works in Python 2 and 3. Function api calls are the same as in PIL or pillow but internally it works with OpenCV and numpy to load, save and manipulate images. Have a look at https://github.com/bunkahle/PILasOPENCV or install it with pip install PILasOPENCV. Not all PIL functions have been simulated but the most common functions work.