# Select image region (programmatically!): Python 3, matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have an image and want to get somehow a new image which will be a rectangle region of the original image centered at the middle point of the original image. Say, the original image is 1000x1000 pixels and I want to get the region of the size 501x501 in the center the original image.

Any way to do it using Python 3 and/or matplotlib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `image.crop` method from the PIL library seems to be up the task:
http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm

For example:

```
br@ymir:~/temp$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Image
>>> im=Image.open('self.jpg')
>>> im.size
(180, 181)
>>> box=(10,10,100,100)
>>> im1=im.crop(box)
>>> im1.show()
>>>
```

Comment: Apparently, there are some python-3 PIL ports, see here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896286/image-library-for-python-3 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188552/are-there-image-processing-modules-for-python-3

Comment: Good to know, but I would try to use as few libraries as possible. I already use matplotlib, so will try to check the suggested solution based on matplotlib.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there is no official matplotlib release for python 3 (and no PIL).

However [matplotlib dev](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib) should be compatible.

You can use matplotlib and numpy indexing to achieve this without using other tools.
However matplotlib only supports [png natively](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/image_tutorial.html#importing-image-data-into-numpy-arrays).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.cbook as mplcbook

lena = mplcbook.get_sample_data('lena.png')
# the shape of the image is 512x512
img = mpimg.imread(lena)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5.12, 5.12))

ax1 = plt.axes([0, 0, 1, 1], frameon=False)
ax1.imshow(img)

center = (300, 320) # center of the region
extent = (100, 100) # extend of the region
ax2 = plt.axes([0.01, 0.69, 0.3, 0.3])
img2 = img[(center[1] - extent[1]):(center[1] + extent[1]),
           (center[0] - extent[0]):(center[0] + extent[0]),:]
ax2.imshow(img2)
ax2.set_xticks([])
ax2.set_yticks([])
plt.savefig('lena.png', dpi=100)
```

[image: lena.png]

Comment: Thanks for the good example! As I understand if jpg will be given, PIL is required? Unfortunately I have all images in jpg... Is there any way to save jpg as png within python/matplotlib without using PIL?

Comment: @Katya the docs say it only supports png. so you should need PIL.