# Convert a jpg to a list of lists

Tags: python, list, jpeg

I'm trying to figure out how to convert a jpg into a list of lists (using python 3.2.3) such that:

```
[ 
[red,blue,red,etc..],           #line1
[blue,red,yellow, etc...],      #line2
[orange,yellow,black,etc...],   #Last Line
]
```

Basically each list within the main list represents a horizontal line of colour values starting from the top of the image.

I thought it was going to be easy, just write a little script to extract the data from the jpg file. Hah! After looking into that I realized that was going to be a lot more work than I really want to do.

So far I'm thinking converting it to a bitmap and then writing the data into a suitable format is my best bet. Of course then I have to figure out how to extract the info from a bitmap.

Now since I'm sure other people have had to do this before, someone must know a far easier way I can go about that. I've tried looking around but haven't had any luck so far.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into the Python Imaging Library (PIL)?

Comment: Do you have an (unstated) ultimate goal in mind once converted, or are you really just seeking a way to turn the tidy, standardized image format into an unwieldy list of lists?

Comment: thought I'd try my hand at some ocr stuff. Seemed like it should be easy enough. Famous last words eh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) and open your image:
2. Open your image AS Numpy array (make sure numpy is installed):

   ```
   image = numpy.asarray(Image.open('pic.jpg'))
   ```
3. Use numpy.split to split your resulting array into lists:

   ```
   lists = numpy.split(image)
   ```

play with your lists.

Comment: The PIL library doesn't seem to support versions of Python above 3. Is there another way to do that?

Comment: @JasonWhite try working out with the PIL's 2.7 version - I think it'll work.

Comment: Even better, Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pil. Found this in another answer here at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188552/are-there-image-processing-modules-for-python-3