# Python: corverting a greyscale BMP into a list of lists

Tags: python, list, bitmap

My question is somewhat similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788087/convert-a-jpg-to-a-list-of-lists), but I couldn't figure out how to make it work for me. I want to convert a grayscale bmp of arbitrary size into a list of lists with values between 0 and 255. 
For example: 

 If input looks like this: [image: grayscale bmp] 

 The output should be:

```
pic =  [[255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 127, 127, 0  , 0  , 127, 127, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 127, 127, 0  , 0  , 127, 127, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]]
```

I have almost no experience in image processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using PIL library :

```
In [1]: from PIL import Image
In [2]: img = Image.open('HrWCY.png')
In [3]: img.getdata().getpixel((0,0))
Out[3]: 0
In [4]: img.getdata().getpixel((4,4))
Out[4]: 255
In [5]: img.getdata().getpixel((5,7))
Out[5]: 164
In [6]: img.getdata().getpixel((12,12))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-8456667c785c> in <module>()
----> 1 img.getdata().getpixel((12,12))
IndexError: image index out of range
```

Check the [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/), you should fine better methods for the purpose.