# Graphs, plots in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I've been teaching myself the basics of programming using Python 3 and now want to delve into more mathematical/graphical stuff (e.g. plotting fractals).

Everything I find for graphs (e.g. pyLab, matplotlib) seems to be incompatible with Python 3, though I did find a version of numpy I could install. Does anyone know of modules that are compatible with version 3, or know when pylab might become compatible?

Should I go back and learn/install an earlier version of Python?

Comment: for imaging: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896286/image-library-for-python-3. I once used tkinter for a mandelbrot generator but it was awful slow.

Comment: Not everything has been ported to 3. You're probably better off with 2.7 and keeping aware of the differences so that everything you do can be run in 3.2 as well

Comment: @Ben That's a wrong thought. People should be using only Python 3 to make a pressure on software developers.

Comment: If you want to "make a pressure on software developers", then use Python 3. If you want to write working code, you may have to use Python 2. Not many people come to SO complaining that their code doesn't put enough pressure on the developers of third party libraries.

Comment: @JBernardo, it's a fair point but until the specific modules one needs have been ported it's not always viable to use Python 3. And if you're unable to do the porting yourself you have no choice but to use what is currently available and remembering to use `!=` not `<>` etc.