# No module named pylab

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I just upgraded to python3 on Fedora, and was trying to import `pylab`. But instead I got an error

```
ImportError: No module named 'pylab'
```

After some research I found [some information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223808/graphs-plots-in-python-3) about installing a package `matplotlib-py3k` to make it work. However, the link to the page is down! Maybe there is a `yum install` package I can use to simply install `pylab` to work with python3?

The package for python2.x is installed and working.

Comment: Have you tried: `yum install python-matplot*`?

Comment: Yes, does not fix the problem.

Comment: I don't think matplotlib is available for python 3 in Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

Try `yum install python-matplotlib`. If I am mistaken, then you can try from the source.

From the `matplotlib` website...

> If you are on Fedora/RedHat, you can get all the dependencies required
>   to build matplotlib by first installing `yum-builddep` and then running:
>   `su -c "yum-builddep python-matplotlib"` This does not build matplotlib,
>   but it does get all of the build dependencies, which will make
>   building from source easier.

Then you can use `git clone git@github.com:matplotlib/matplotlib.git` to git `matplotlib` and then install with `cd matplotlib` and `python setup.py install`.

Comment: I just tried `yum install python-matplotlib`. Something was installed, but I get the same error again. Maybe I have to change the installed pylab from version 2 to 3, change path, add path, remove old installation, type something else, ...?

Comment: Did you try the second part to do if the `yum install` didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install matplotlib for python3 by performing:

```
yum install python3-matplotlib
```