# no module named pylab on windows

Tags: python, matplotlib

I faced this issue yesterday. I saw the following questions:
[No module named pylab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828795/)
[python error: no module named pylab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965336/)

Both of the above questions gave instructions for Linux and not for Windows machines.

**The Problem**
I have heard about the pylab package for plotting in python.
I opened the shell and tried this and...

```
>>> import pylab

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pylab
ImportError: No module named pylab
```

I then installed matplotlib and scipy but could not find the .exe file for numpy.

**So, could someone**
Please help me with installing pylab for python 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is just one step. Go to the following link and download the `.msi` file and then run it. It is a simple installation that installs a new EPD  IDLE which comes enabled with numpy, scipy and pylab.

[EPD Package](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd_free.php)

On this site you can download the `.msi` file. Registration is not required unless you want to update the packages. This IDLE is some version of Python 2.7.

Answer (score 11):

You just need to install, `matplotlib` library and it will work fine. I had the same error but solved by that.

`pip install matplotlib`

Comment: I think that this one should actually be the correct answer.

Answer (score -2):

If you just want to install pylab which comes under matplotlib package, and numpy & scipy in windows then you may uninstall the current ones(that don't work) from pip by command

```
 pip uninstall package_name
```

Then get the latest binary installer for numpy, scipy and matplotlib from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) selecting your version of python and windows 32 or 64 bit. Then install it as normal software installer. Make sure it finds your version of python during the installation. This is it !!

After installation, type in the python shell

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.show()
```

This ensures that matplotlib is correctly installed on your machine!!