# no module named matplotlib on windows

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, anaconda

Facing this issue right now, saw the question:
[no module named pylab on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447422/no-module-named-pylab-on-windows)

I have annaconda and python 2.7 installed. I tried in the python shell:

```
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

and received the following result. I've checked my PATH variable, and I'm not sure how to resolve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have `matplotlib` installed?

Comment: Try `pip show matplotlib` to check for it.

Comment: It looks like this is not the version of python provided with anaconda. The name "anaconda" should appear when you launch python.

Comment: this is it, I needed to put anaconda at the top of my system variables for windows 10