# PIL for Python 3.2 on Windows or alternatives?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm building my first Python program :) However, I installed Python 3.2 instead of 2.7, as the newer version has `TkInter` included. Now I can't find a way to use PIL in it.

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896286/image-library-for-python-3) but as a total newcomer it's not much help for me. I installed zlib and the libjpeg but couldn't get any further when it comes to building the pil-py3k. I have no idea what I am supposed to do in here:

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Library pointers.
#
# Use None to look for the libraries in well-known library locations.
# Use a string to specify a single directory, for both the library and
# the include files.  Use a tuple to specify separate directories:
# (libpath, includepath).  Examples:
#
# JPEG_ROOT = "/home/libraries/jpeg-6b"
# TIFF_ROOT = "/opt/tiff/lib", "/opt/tiff/include"
#
# If you have "lib" and "include" directories under a common parent,
# you can use the "libinclude" helper:
#
# TIFF_ROOT = libinclude("/opt/tiff")

FREETYPE_ROOT = None
JPEG_ROOT = None
TIFF_ROOT = None
ZLIB_ROOT = None
TCL_ROOT = None
```

Is there an easier way to enable PIL with PNG and JPEG support for Python 3?

One option is to download an older version of Python but then there won't be `TkInter`?

I wish you understand I'm a newcomer so please forgive me if I make any stupid questions. Python seems really cool! ;) Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check out this [unofficial packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), they should work on py3k.

Comment: Also, `tkinter` comes with Python 2.7 too, http://docs.python.org/library/tkinter.html, it's just organized / named differently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unofficial PIL for Python 3.2 is the answer
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 5):

Just found out that there is PIL fork Pillow: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

As agf mentioned in his comment on your question, tkinter has been included with every version of Python for years. The important difference is a restructuring of the tkinter packages. The biggest of those changes is the base package name: In Python 3.x, the tkinter package is named `tkinter`, while in Python 2.x, the package is named `Tkinter` (note the capital "T"). You can see the [Python 2.7.2 docs](http://docs.python.org/library/tkinter.html) on tkinter for more information.

Unfortunately, I haven't used PIL with Python 3.x, so I can't be of any assistance there, but hopefully you can accomplish what you need in 2.7 instead.

Answer (score 0):

See http://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2012-October/007080.html for an updated port that works on Python 2+3