# No module named Image tk

Tags: python

I am new to python can any body please Help

```
D:\python\sub>python app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
    import ImageTk
ImportError: No module named ImageTk
```

Comment: Do you have the Python Imaging Library (PIL) installed?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This says that python is installed in non-standard location so the OS can not find ImageTk as it look in standard locations. You can re-install Python in a standard location, and where that is depends on which operating system and which installer you are using, or append this location to sys.path.
I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 and I simply install ImageTk package by using terminal like:

```
sudo apt-get install python-imaging-tk
```

Comment: If you are using Python 3 + Pillow on Ubuntu, the package name is  `python3-pil.imagetk`.

Comment: for info, this won't work for the command by pip install python-imaging-tk

Comment: @kennytm This is likely to be the answer everybody will need today.

Comment: changed to `python-pil.imagetk` for python 2.7.

Comment: For fedora 'sudo dnf install python3-pillow-tk'

Answer (score 15):

I had to import the PIL.ImageTk module separately. The line of code

```
      import PIL
```

did not import the PIL.ImageTk module and I had to additionally use

```
      from PIL import ImageTk
```

and then it worked fine in the Enthought Canopy 1.0 distribution of Python 2.7.

The need for that solution was suggested by this redhat bug resolution:https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=247171

This could also be accomplished with `import PIL.ImageTk`.

Comment: Why do the authors of PIL choose to omit `import ImageTk` from PIL/__init__.py?

Answer (score 7):

The code that you are using should be installed separately from the normal python installation, in fact comes from PIL libray (Python Imaging Library) which is an external library, an add on.

Beware that the PIL library doesn't work on python version 3.0 and over, but is still working only on python 2.x series, so if you have python 3.x installed you should first install a python 2.x  and than download and install the corresponding PIL Library.

Here a link to [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) library, you can download from here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that the ImageTK module has been installed. It is part of the Python Imaging Library (PIL) which can be found [here](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)

I would also suggest you read the official Python tutorial on [Modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html).

Answer (score 2):

For windows (with Anaconda and Python 3.x), the solution is proposed here :
[Pillow installation for python 3.x [and Anaconda]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407185/pil-for-python-3-2-on-windows-or-alternatives)

Install Pillow with pip after downloading the whl file