# ubuntu python pip can't uninstall pillow

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library

When I try to uninstall pillow using pip ,it outputs:

```
qixin@qixin:~$ pip uninstall pillow
Uninstalling Pillow:
  /usr/local/bin/pilconvert.py
  ......
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pillow-2.7.0.egg-info
Proceed (y/n)? y
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/uninstall.py", line 59, in run
    requirement_set.uninstall(auto_confirm=options.yes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1035, in uninstall
    req.uninstall(auto_confirm=auto_confirm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 598, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1836, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 295, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 303, in move
    os.unlink(src)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/pilconvert.py'

Storing debug log for failure in /tmp/tmpEmRbAF
```

My OS is ubuntu 14.04,python's version is 2.7.
Why did it fail? Thanks much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the command you ran didn't have the correct operating system level permissions. On windows, that command would have worked fine, but on Ubuntu pip needs `sudo` added before it so that it is root and can get the correct permissions.

You should enter `sudo pip uninstall pillow`.

Answer (score 1):

I had to upgrade pip itself, then it worked.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: This was very helpful. I couldn't solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630736/no-module-named-image-tk), because I couldn't upgrade Pillow, because I couldn't uninstall it until I upgraded pip.

Answer (score 0):

Permission denied. Try `sudo pip uninstall pillow`.

Answer (score 0):

Before installing the dependencies in requirements.txt file, run the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev libsasl2-dev libldap2-dev build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev libmysqlclient-dev libjpeg-dev libpq-dev libjpeg8-dev liblcms2-dev libblas-dev libatlas-base-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very late to answer this but for anyone still struggling with thie error. This did it for me. Updating pip 1st, then proceed to install Pillow.

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
```