# python tkinter display animated GIF using PIL

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, animated-gif

Is there any way to display an animated GIF in Tkinter using Python Image Library?

I thought the [ImageSequence module](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagesequence.htm) would be the way to do it, but I don't  know how to use it and if it's possible.

The first question is if there is any easy way. For example: load a GIF using PIL and the ImageSequence and just draw it on a Tkinter window using `ImageTk.PhotoImage` and it will be animated.

Or do I have to set up a function myself, using the `after` method or something like `time.sleep` to loop through the GIF frames and draw them on a tkinter window?

The second question: even if I have to make a function to loop through the GIF frames, is the ImageSequence module supposed to do this or PIL has another module for it?

I'm using Python 3.1 and a [private port of PIL](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pil), indicated in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896286/image-library-for-python-3).

Answer (score 6):

> Newsgroups: comp.lang.python
>
> From: "Fredrik Lundh"
>
> Date: Mon, 1 May 2006
>
> Daniel Nogradi wrote:
>
> 'The source distribution of the 1.1.4 version comes with a Scripts
>   directory where you can find player.py, gifmaker.py and explode.py
>   which all deal with animated gif.'

they're still shipped with 1.1.5 (and 1.1.6), and they should work.

if all you're missing is a few files from the script directory, you can get
them here:

http://svn.effbot.org/public/pil/Scripts/

---

player.py is run from the command line

see if this one works for you:

```
from Tkinter import * 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class MyLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, master, filename):
        im = Image.open(filename)
        seq =  []
        try:
            while 1:
                seq.append(im.copy())
                im.seek(len(seq)) # skip to next frame
        except EOFError:
            pass # we're done

        try:
            self.delay = im.info['duration']
        except KeyError:
            self.delay = 100

        first = seq[0].convert('RGBA')
        self.frames = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(first)]

        Label.__init__(self, master, image=self.frames[0])

        temp = seq[0]
        for image in seq[1:]:
            temp.paste(image)
            frame = temp.convert('RGBA')
            self.frames.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(frame))

        self.idx = 0

        self.cancel = self.after(self.delay, self.play)

    def play(self):
        self.config(image=self.frames[self.idx])
        self.idx += 1
        if self.idx == len(self.frames):
            self.idx = 0
        self.cancel = self.after(self.delay, self.play)        


root = Tk()
anim = MyLabel(root, 'animated.gif')
anim.pack()

def stop_it():
    anim.after_cancel(anim.cancel)

Button(root, text='stop', command=stop_it).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks but, I'm a bit new to Python, how do I actually use the script? I've imported tkinter, PIL and player, and already opened the image, I've tried `animation = player.UI(root, im)` and some variations. Is the UI class in the player script a Label? When I try to pack() it, it says "UI object has no attribute tk", and if I don't pack() or grid(), nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Simple PIL version:

```
canvas = Image.new("RGB",(Width,Height),"white")
gif = Image.open('text.gif', 'r')
frames = []
try:
    while 1:
        frames.append(gif.copy())
        gif.seek(len(frames))
except EOFError:
    pass

for frame in frames:
     canvas.paste(frame)
     canvas.show()
```

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to only copy the first frame