# PIL 1.1.7 and python 3.x

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Image library for Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896286/image-library-for-python-3)

How can I use PIL 1.1.7 in python 3.x, it says it needs an 2.4 ver. of python, but I have seen it being used ( just never got around to ask how it was done).

The version I saw was that somehow the PIL 1.1.7 was defined and then later used in python 3.x code.

Thanks for any help beforehand!

Comment: it says it supports up to `2.6` http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/.

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) for some unofficial PIL downloads. Works for me.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but how exactly did this link help? I don't even see distributions of PIL in there.

Comment: @BenFarmer: You're right, it appears PIL is no longer listed on that page. Pillow is the way to go nowadays.