# Display google static map in a PDF with Python 3

Tags: python, image, api, pdf

I have to include an image (map) into a PDF file in Python3.

I get the image from google static map API, using an URL like this one:

> http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=12&size=300x300&markers=46.75165,6.98996&sensor=false

The Image function of PyPDF

```
pdf.image(name, x=None, y=None, w=0, h=0, type='PNG', link='')
```

Give me this error:

> RuntimeError: FPDF error: Not a PNG file: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=12&size=300x300&markers=&sensor=false

I think it's beacause of the image dosen't have any extension?

Any other way? Idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Static Maps API returns a GIF-format image in response to a HTTP request via a URL

Therefore, try GIF and not PNG as type :)

Source: http://blog.programmableweb.com/2008/02/25/google-releases-static-maps-api/

Comment: Ok, thanks! But now, I have got the error: RuntimeError: FPDF error: PIL is required for GIF support. PIL is not supported in Python 3? Have you got an idea? Thanks

Comment: Of course you'll need an alternative to PIL (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896286/image-library-for-python-3 ) then you'll need to get the image and convert it to a supported format. Then work with that