# Python Button Transparency Tkinter

Tags: python, image, button, tkinter, transparency

I'm having an issue where I need a button to have transparency where there are blank textures. I've already removed everything that isn't the Krabby Patty itself in the image but the blank parts show up white. I've searched through some topics already to no avail so I'm sorry if there's already an answer to this somewhere.

This is what it currently looks like: [image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNR7W.png

Comment: Please add the code you are using to the question.

Comment: @user3422552, Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270209/how-do-i-make-tkinter-support-png-transparency

Answer (score 0):

Use IrfanView to edit the transparent properties and that should fix it.