# Import a circle as an image and keep the background of the circle transparent

Tags: tkinter, python-imaging-library, python-3.6

I would like to import a circle as an image and keep the background of the circle transparent. I was also wondering whether I could combine canvas with normal tkinter to do this?

I heard you could do something with *rgba* and *alpha channels set to 0* (or something similar), but I really don't understand it, and I don't know what program to use to do that anyway.

Comment: what do you mean by "combine canvas with normal tkinter"? The canvas already is part of "normal" tkinter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make Tkinter support PNG transparency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270209/how-do-i-make-tkinter-support-png-transparency)

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to import a circle? In tkinter you can simply create a circle canvas object (of any size and thickness) in tkinter.Canvas and overlay it above any image you have import into tkinter.Canvas. Is this what you want to do?

Comment: Well I don't have an amazing (or much of a at all) grasp of canvas so I don't really know how well it would interact with my labels and buttons that I currently have. The reason I think it may not is because I want the circle to move around and I don't think a circle made with canvas will operate by the same movement rules (or code) as my current label that does it and I don't want to have to mess around with that.

Comment: If I used canvas it would mean I would probably have to rewrite my entire code.