# Looking for modules/libaries to style my Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm looking to add stuff to my Tkinter GUI to make it look fancy. Ideas are squares bouncing around, snow effects, lightning, etc.

Comment: questions asking us to recommend software are off topic on stack overflow. You might have better luck asking on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use images to achieve some of things you are after. If you use a .png you can keep the background [transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270209/how-do-i-make-tkinter-support-png-transparency). You can then overlay this onto of everything else.

Another way that you might want to look into is using [turtle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html).