# Draw transparent images over vlc in Tkinter

Tags: image, tkinter, canvas, transparency, vlc

I'm embedding VLC in my Tkinter app and I want to draw transparent images on it.
The problem is that Tkinter does not support transparency except for canvas.

If I add a canvas background image with create_image, I can't pass its `winfo_id` to `set_xwindow()` because the image is an int:

```
player.set_xwindow(image_on_canvas.winfo_id())
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'winfo_id'
```

I need to pass the image to add other transparent images over it.
If I create a frame or label to play VLC then I can't draw transparent images over it.

Comment: In fact I have the similar question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56554692/ with vlc playing instead of fixed background.

Comment: `image_on_canvas` is a canvas object id (a python `int`) so you can't call `winfo_id` on it and you can't pass it in `player.set_xwindow(...)`. Also I don't think it's possible to add anything with transparency over the VLC player.